# Fixing Flutter GitHub Project Import Error: Dart SDK Version and Null Safety Compatibility

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec.yaml, flutter-pubspec

While importing any project in flutter from github it shows The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0' or higher to enable null safety.  The current Dart SDK (3.2.3) only supports null safety....? How to overcome this error?

Tried pub get ,pub upgrade and pub outdated but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Your SDK bounds should be `sdk: '>=2.7.0 <4.0.0'`

Because you are using SDK 3.2.3 and bounds are between `2.7.0` to `3.0.0`

> So to solve this problem, just increase the upper version of SDK to
> `4.0.0`